# c++ confusion on outputs

Tags: c++, loops, output

This might seem like a stupid question, but i just dont understand the difference between these functions. Setting both of these to 0, why does xxx() print 0,2,4,6,4,2,0 and xxy() print the regular 0,1,2,3,4,5. The question i'm asking is, why does xxx() reduce after it hits the max value allowed '6'

```
void xxx(int N) 
{
    cout << N;
    if (N < 5) 
    {
        xxx(N + 2);
        cout << N;;
    }
}
void xxy(int N) 
{
    cout << N;
    if (N < 5)
        xxy(N + 1);
}

int main()
{
   xxx(0);
   xxy(0);

}
```

Comment: You might want to check how recursion works. Get a better understanding.

Comment: @learningToCode the basics you mean? i'm missing something fundamental arent i?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code line by line. It will help you get a much better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: ohh, so the recursive function keeps going until the value is back to the original value for that integer. i think i get it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well... Pay atención here:

```
cout << N;
if (N < 5) 
{
    xxx(N + 2);
    cout << N;
}
```

When we have a recursive call as xxx(N+2) the current "iteration" is stacked to start the new function. Then when the function ends, the previous iteration proceeds normally.

Therefore when the max value (6) is reached, this iteration will end continuing with a cout of the previous "iteration"... In this previous iteration the N value was 4... This value will be displayed and this iteration will end continuing with the cout of N in the previous iteration that will be 2 and so on...

In the second function notes that there isnt a cout after of the xxy recursive call, but if you put it, a similar behavior will be displayed.

I hope you have understood me... Greetings